# Block based code conversion?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I am new to using block based code so I need to know how to convert the below code to block based in order to make it a little more efficient. Also what firmware adopted Block based code?

```
    - (NSString *)removeBadWordsFromString:(NSString *)string {

    for (NSString * word in badWords){
        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:word withString:@"" 
                                                      options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
    }

    return string;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    [textField setText:[self removeBadWordsFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, string]]];

    return (string.length == 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are referring specifically to using Grand Central Dispatch with block (as opposed to just using blocks).  However, the issue here is that as the code is written, you can't take advantage of concurrency because you are modifying the string within the removeBadWordsFromString.  If you tried to edit that string on multiple threads at the same time, very bad things could (and would) happen if the string weren't handled in an atomic matter.  If the string is handled in an atomic matter, then you wouldn't get a performance increase because it could only act on it one at a time.

For more information on concurrency, you really need to read Apple's document on concurrency which explains this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html